# Excel のデータを VBA で SQLite に挿入する方法を知りたい

Tags: vba, excel, sqlite

現在、ConfigやExcelのパラメータシートを比較するシステムをSQLiteを使用して作成しています。
SQLiteにExcelのデータを書き込むVBAを作りたいと思っています。
現在、テーブルの作成は完了しております。

Excelで該当のデータを探す事は完了したという前提で、その後にどのようにDBに接続してテーブルに書き込むVBAを作成すれば良いのか教えていただけませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

マイクロソフト製品からデータベースに接続するには
一般的にODBC Driverと呼ばれるものを利用します。
これを用いることで共通のインターフェースからいろいろなデータベースにアクセスすることかできます。
SQLite向けのODBCドライバは下記のURLからダウンロードできるようです。

http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

ただその組み合わせについてはSQLiteForExcelというソフトウェアも有名なようです。
https://github.com/govert/SQLiteForExcel

英語が読めるならダウンロードしてチュートリアルやサンプルを追ってみるのがいいですし、製品名で検索すれば国内で利用されている方が見つかると思いますので調べてみてください。

https://qiita.com/hisayuki/items/9b42624790ba74a2fb35
https://qiita.com/hisayuki/items/cd1b6d7bd1a8293647c8